# Why are the request headers in the following Angular 5 code not been passed in the request?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, post, angular5

So I can't get this http request object to send my headers along with request.

```
   loginUser(email,password){     
   console.log("loginuser");     
   let formData:FormData = new FormData();  
   formData.append("format","json");
   formData.append("email",email);
   formData.append("password",password);      
   let headers = new HttpHeaders();       
   headers.append('command', 'ProcessLoginPos');                    
   headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');    
   const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/ProjectOne/', formData, {         'headers':headers,      reportProgress: true,       responseType: 'text'      });
return this.http.request(req,{},{"command": "ProcessLoginPos"});   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last line should follow this pattern:

```
return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers, params: params })
```

And finally you should get something like:

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/ProjectOne/', formData, { headers: headers })
```

Result (but I have no idea, why do you need `new FormData()` here):

```
loginUser(email, password) {         
   let formData: FormData = new FormData();  
   formData.append("format", "json");
   formData.append("email", email);
   formData.append("password", password);      
   let headers = new HttpHeaders();       
   headers.append('command', 'ProcessLoginPos');                    
   headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');    
   return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/ProjectOne/', formData, { headers: headers })   
}
```

Comment: Its still not working e.g. I get the request in the server but I don't get the headers that I set in the client.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, your solution worked!

Comment: @AntonioTapia, nice to hear that)